# Apply-templates with in Analyze string

Tags: regex, xslt-2.0

I've the below XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <para align="center">
        <content-style font-style="bold">A.1 This is the first text</content-style> (This is second text)
      </para>
```

Below are my 2 Questions.

1. here i've declared a regex to match the `content-style`, But when i run this the second one is caught where as it should be `div class="para"`, but in the output i get `<div class="para align-center">`. please let me know where am i going wrong.
2. Is there a way i can `apply-templates` with in the match. when i tried it throws me an error. I want it like below.

if (para)

```
xsl:apply-templates select child::node()[not(self::text)]
```

else

```
xsl:apply-templates
```

[Working Example](http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzQn/1)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `apply-templates` inside the `analyze-string` then you need to store the context node outside of analyze-string in a variable `<xsl:variable name="context-node" select="."/>`, then you can use `<xsl:apply-templates select="$context-node/node()"/>` for instance to process the child nodes.

Whether you need that approach I am not sure, I wonder whether you can not simply use the `matches` functions in a pattern e.g. `<xsl:template match="para[content-style[matches(., '(\w+)\.(\w+)')]]">...</xsl:template>`.